# gstreamer help/advice regarding decklinkvideosrc to avi out via a qtmux

Tags: gstreamer

I am currently trying to use gstreamer to record a duplicate of my PC output but I am struggling to find a pipeline that works.

The requirements I am trying to meet are:

- decklinkvideo & decklinkaudio in
- encode into h264 via my recording machines built in gpu (vaapih264enc)
- output to an avi container.

The closest I have come so far is the following pipeline:

```
GST_DEBUG=3,decklink:5 gst-launch-1.0 -e decklinkvideosrc mode=1080p60 ! queue ! videoconvert ! vaapipostproc ! vaapih264enc tune=low-power ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. qtmux name=mux ! filesink location=/home/user/video_a.avi
```

However, this results in a video which is green and red only and the scale is way off.[output video frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCIx1.jpg)

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well for starters you use `qtmux`. The result will be a mp4/mov file. Renaming the file to avi does not change that. But no one should save H.264 in AVI anyway.

Comment: I managed to fix this issue but I am curious to understand your response a little bit more. 

You're saying that the qtmux will encode the video stream to mp4 and the container is a mp4/mov even if we rename it to avi?

On your second remark you're saying I shouldn't be using h264 inside an AVI, can you explain why not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no specification for H.264 in AVI. Specifically AVI does not have support for variable framerate, cannot correctly handle B-frames from "modern" codecs that support these.

Comment: Thank you for that insight Florian, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue with the following pipeline:

```
GST_DEBUG=3,decklink:5 gst-launch-1.0 -e decklinkvideosrc ! queue ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. decklinkaudiosrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! mux. qtmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

It seems that the vaapih264enc does not support I420 format when using the free drivers which the kernel pre-installs. Therefore, you could fix this issue with the below pipeline. Here we are converting the I420 into NV12.

```
GST_DEBUG=3,decklink:5 gst-launch-1.0 -e decklinkvideosrc mode=1080p60 ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=NV12 ! vaapih264enc tune=low-power ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. qtmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.avi
```

You can also fix this by installing the non-free va drivers with:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-media-va-driver-non-free
```

Then run the below command to check they have been installed correct. The non-free driver unlocks high-power mode for the vaapih264enc and support for I420 format.

```
sudo vainfo
```

If you did install the non-free driver then the following pipeline should work for you with vaapih264enc running in high powered mode.

```
GST_DEBUG=3,decklink:5 gst-launch-1.0 -e decklinkvideosrc mode=1080p60 ! queue ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. decklinkaudiosrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! mux. qtmux name=mux ! filesink location=test.avi
```